# TextViews fill the available space but never clip the content

Tags: android, layout, localization, textview

I have (horizontal) scrollview with some textview. I want these textview to fill all the space on the screen and divide the space between them evenly. Sort of like a viewpagerstrip

However, I have realized that in some languages the translation of my strings are longer than the textview and clips the text. Is there a way to make sure the content of a (single line) textview is never clipped.

The remaning textview should just divide the remaning space. If there is not space enough I want them to go outside the screen.

Comment: @La5t5tarfighter I am not aware of that. However, the background of the textviews are different, so unless that also overflows I do not think it will work.

Comment: do you want the textview to scroll like a marquee? or you just dont care if you cant see the whole thing?

Answer (score 0):

before oncreate

```
    TextView ticker;
```

in oncreate

```
 ticker = findViewById(R.id.ticker);

        ticker.setFocusable(true);
        ticker.requestFocus();
        ticker.setSelected(true);
```

here is the xml

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/ticker"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:background="#fff000"
     android:ellipsize="marquee"
     android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
     android:fadingEdgeLength="5dp"
     android:focusable="false"
     android:gravity="bottom"
     android:lines="1"
     android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
     android:singleLine="true"
     android:text="@string/ticker"
     android:textColor="#000000"
     android:textColorHighlight="#FFFFFF"
     android:textSize="30sp" />
```